# Unresolved attribute reference 'next' for class 'Iterable' in os.walk().next()

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm, iterable

When I'm typing something like this in PyCharm IDE 3.0.2 Community Edition (Python 2.7.x):

```
directory = '/home/user/dir'
samples_list = os.walk(directory).next()[1]
```

I get warning in IDE **Unresolved attribute reference 'next' for class 'Iterable'**.

So, I want to know if this is error because of IDE (http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-11401) or I should do something with my code.

**UPD1:** Unfortunately, this is a bug in Pycharm [PY-12017](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-12017)

Comment: Are you sure these are the lines instigating the error? `os.walk(directory)` is of type `generator`, not `Iterable` (and there is no class called `Iterable` in the standard library.)

Comment: Yep, this line is highlighted in IDE and **.next()** part is highlighted too.

Comment: @unutbu: [generators *are* iterators](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: yes, but why would PyCharm capitalize `Iterables` as though it were the name of the class?

Comment: @unutbu: Most likely it is using the [`collections` abstract base class](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Iterable)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Any guess why PyCharm would want to refer to the class by the less-specific ABC instead of `type(x).__name__`?

Comment: @unutbu: I think it uses the ABCs to implement auto-completion and linting. And it got a false-positive on `Iterable` before testing for `Iterator`, or some such bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your IDE is incorrect, in Python 2 iterators (including generators like `os.walk()`) do have a [`.next()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.next).

You can also use the built-in [`next()` *function*](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next):

```
samples_list = next(os.walk(directory))[1]
```

I suspect the IDE mismatched the generator against the [`collections.Iterable` ABC](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Iterable), while generators are [`Iterator`s](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Iterator) too.